# Dependent fields in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm in the process of designing models for a `Django` app and I can't quite work out how to approach a problem.

I have 3 models. `Server`, `Module`, and `Device`.

`Server` is a server that a module could run on.
`Module` runs on a server, and contains devices.

The problem with `Devices` is that the name is always a field, but the attributes could change.

I considered just putting a `JSON` value in attributes but I couldn't figure out how to do that with Django admin.

Basically the user will enter a name for the device and depending on which module it is attached to, show various different fields to fill in.

For example:

```
module rfm_ninjablock:
Device fields would be "name" and "code"

module LimitlessLED
Device fields would be "name", "controller", "group" and "LightID"
```

Is there a straightforward way to do it or am I going about it the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to make a fourth model: `DeviceAttribute`.

- Each Device has a name and has zero or more `DeviceAttribute`s.
- A `DeviceAttribute` has two fields: `key` and `value`.

Alternatively, you could use the JSON you suggested, but you wouldn't be able to query on it or update it as easily. It's a bit of an anti-pattern.

**UPDATE:** If you have several "classes" of `Device`s, then rather than having arbitrary attributes, you can achieve type-safety by subclassing your models.

There are [several ways](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance) to do this. I have often used the [multi-table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) approach.

It creates a `OneToOneField` between `DeviceSubclassA` and `Device`, and between `DeviceSubclassB` and `Device`.

You can add certain fields to `DeviceSubclassA`, and different fields to `DeviceSubclassB`. The common `name` attribute is on the `Device` parent model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. the reason I was thinking of json is that I want to force the DeviceAttributes to be certain things for certain device types...

Comment: Thanks! After several hours investigating I have decided to use django signals to insert a empty json object into a column when the device is created, so that it can be completely dynamic. I will make your answer as an answer though, as if I didn't want to be dynamic this would do the job!